# Running Distinct Count in Pandas by a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df', with the following structure:

**Input:**

| ID | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 | 10 |
| 2 | P1 | 11 |
| 3 | P2 | 12 |
| 4 | P2 | 12 |
| 5 | P2 | 15 |

**Expected Output:**

| ID | Product | Price | Distinct_Running_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | P1 | 11 | 2 |
| 3 | P2 | 12 | 1 |
| 4 | P2 | 12 | 1 |
| 5 | P2 | 15 | 2 |

**Problem:**

I want to create a new column called 'Distinct_Running_Count', with the following logic:

- Perform a running distinct count of a column 'Product' based on
  price
- Some products don't have any price change, thus 'Distinct_Running_Count' will be 1
- Every subsequent price change, the 'Distinct_Running_Count' will be incremented

**Solutions Tried:**

```
df['Distinct_Running_Count'] = df.groupby(['Product', 'Price']).cumcount() + 1
```

```
df['Distinct_Running_Count'] = df.groupby(['Product', 'Price']).transform('nunique')
```

**Issue:**

The above solution either provides running count or the total uniques counts but not what I expect

Comment: What if the price goes from 12, 12, 15, 14, 15?

Comment: Any price change the price_count should increase

Comment: Did you try two different solutions? It looks like one solution with two lines after the most recent edit.

Comment: Yes i tried both solutions, one with 'cumcount' and one with 'nuinque'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to compare the row and next row in `Price` column and calculate the `cumsum`

```py
df['Distinct_Running_Count'] = (df.groupby(['Product'])['Price']
                                .transform(lambda col: col.ne(col.shift().fillna(col)).cumsum().add(1)))
```

```
print(df)

   ID Product  Price  Distinct_Running_Count
0   1      P1     10                       1
1   2      P1     11                       2
2   3      P2     12                       1
3   4      P2     12                       1
4   5      P2     15                       2
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses a few steps.
First, get the unique rows (based on Product and Price).

Then, use `cumcount()` to create your desired column.

Finally, merge this dataframe with your original dataframe.

```
df_without_dup = df[~df[['Product', 'Price']].duplicated()][['Product', 'Price']]
df_without_dup['Distinct_Running_Count'] = df_without_dup.groupby(['Product']).cumcount() + 1
df = df.merge(df_without_dup, on=['Product', 'Price'], how='left')
```

```
df_without_dup = 
  Product Price  Distinct_Running_Count
0      P1    12                       1
1      P1    11                       2
2      P2    12                       1
4      P2    15                       2
```

Output:

```
  ID Product Price  Distinct_Running_Count
0  1      P1    12                       1
1  2      P1    11                       2
2  3      P2    12                       1
3  4      P2    12                       1
4  5      P2    15                       2
```